# Container div only reaching 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css

I've searched around and found a ton of solutions to this problem, none of which seem to be working for me.

I'm trying to have the .containerBody div stretch all the way to the bottom of the page. When the pages load it appears fine, but on pages with content that you need to scroll to see, the .containerBody div ends at the bottom of the viewport (or, the bottom of the viewport when the page loaded). For pages where the content fits in the initial screen, this is obviously not a problem. For any pages that have more content though, the .containerBody simply ends part way through.

*CSS*

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: Arvo, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11.5px;
    color: #333;
}

.containerBody {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000%;
    background-color: #FCFCFD;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#tagtop {
    width: 240px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    position: relative;
}

.topContent {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 340px;
    padding-left: 647px;
    margin-top: -95px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.topContent a {
    color: #333;
}

.topContent a:hover {
    color: #E9194E;
}

.bonusText {
    display: inline;
    font-family: Arvo,serif;
    font-size: 13.25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #E9194E;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<body>
<div class="containerBody">
    <div id="tagtop"> <a href="index.html"><img src="image.png"</img>
    <h1>Text<div class="bonusText">text</div></h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="topContent"> 
        Text
        <a href="www.google.ca">Link1</a>
        <a href="www.google.ca">Link2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="workcontainer">
        Title<br><br>
        <img src="assets/placeholder.png">
        <div class="workwords">Text</div>
        <div class="worktags">Text</div>
        <img src="assets/placeholder.png">
        <img src="assets/placeholder.png">
        <img src="assets/placeholder.png">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I've tried using min-height and trying to set the top and bottom positions to 0, but I haven't succeeded in making the container stretch to the bottom of the page, rather than the bottom of the loaded viewport. Help?

Comment: why are you using `height:1000%;` inside `.containerBody`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your body a 100% width, and your height a 100% and set your display to block.

```
.containerBody {
 width : 1000px;
 height :100%;
 background-color: #ccc;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 }
 html, body {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 min-height:100%;
 font-family:Arvo, serif;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:11.5px;
  color:#333;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/uCrgy/)

Comment: Can you let me know what elements you changed through CSS? Or did you copy it directly over.

Comment: I just altered the .containerBody div (by adding a display:block; and setting the height to 100%) and the html,body (by giving it a 100% width)

Comment: You didnt add height:100%; you have min-height: 100%; if you want that to work you would have to do max-height: 100%; which doesnt make sense at that point just do height: 100%;

Comment: Oops you're right. That seems to make it work in the jsfiddle, but now in application I'm still running into the same problem.

Since I've started this I have placed it into the site I am working with. In context, the site is  http://www.ohkeith.com/newsite/page.html  and I'm thinking that maybe there is something else interfering

Comment: Are you using firebug to debug the issue?? I assume you are, just gotta ask.

Comment: I am, unfortunately with no luck so far

Comment: On your site I see boxes, going full width.

Comment: The trouble is that white container box in the back (above the background image) on http://www.ohkeith.com/newsite/page.html , when you scroll down, you can see that the container only loaded to the bottom of the initial viewport, rather than right down to the bottom of the content. The purple-gray placeholder boxes go outside of the container and continue down